# How to use ffmpeg with keyframes

Tags: ffmpeg

Here we go again... Keyframes when using ffmpeg. I've read a lot about it but can't seem to get it to work. Some say you need to use GOPSIZE others say keyint and there is some discussion about scenecut...

I'm using the ffmpeg command to stream a webcam to my wowza server.
When using this command everything works as expected:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://*.*.*.*/media/video1 -r 25 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://flash.****.nl/****/_definst_/doPublish=****/teststream
```

At my camera settings i've already said that i want 25fps and a keyframe every 50 but i don't think that ffmpeg takes notice so i've already put in the -r 25 to force 25fps.
But how do i now "force" the keyframe of 50?
I'm trying this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://*.*.*.*/media/video1 -r 25 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 keyint=50:scenecut=-1 -f flv rtmp://flash.****.nl/****/_definst_/doPublish=****/teststream
```

But gives me the error:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libx264'
>   libx264: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, this seems to work, but not sure how to check if it is really doing what im hoping for ;)

ffmpeg -i rtsp://*.*.*.*/media/video1 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -vf "scale=1280:720" -b:v 1500k -keyint_min 25 -g 50 -x264opts no-scenecut -f flv rtmp://******/****/*definst*/doPublish=*****/teststream

Comment: Use ffprobe to check for key_frame flags in the output stream.